# avoid splitting string in middle of word

Tags: jquery

I've the following code below. I'm trying to split a string if the string length is longer than X characters.

Problem is that it sometimes split the string in the middle of a word.

Like this :

```
pursue pleasure r", <-- splitted here
  "ationally encounter
```

Is it posible to split the string, either before or after the word. so it dont break any words?

```js
var str = "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?";

var blocks;
if(str.length > 400){
  blocks = str.match(/.{1,400}/g)
}
console.log(blocks)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`\S` to match any negated whitespace character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)(ie, match until the next whitespace).

```js
var str = "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?";

var blocks;
if(str.length > 400){
  blocks = str.match(/.{1,400}\S*/g)
}
console.log(blocks)
```

---

Or match until the next [word boundary(`\b`)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) with [non-greedy repeat](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)(for the minimal match).

```js
var str = "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally. encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?";

var blocks;
if(str.length > 400){
  blocks = str.match(/.{1,400}.*?\b/g)
  // in case you need `.` as well then use following
  // regex - /.{1,400}.*?\b\.?/g
}
console.log(blocks)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, quick question, the .match seems to break when the string contains a . (dot)

Comment: @TonyNielson what is the expected behaviour ?

Comment: @TonyNielson : try `/.{1,400}.*?\b\.?/g` or in case there is space then  `/.{1,400}.*?\b(\s?\.)?/g`